# How can I capture all the UDP packets using tcpdump?

Tags: tcpdump

I have to capture all the UDP packets sent from host A to any UDP port of host B. The following, if run on host B, doesn't work.

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -SX udp src <hostA>
tcpdump: 'udp' modifier applied to host
```

What is the correct command line to achieve the same?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would use

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -s 0  -w tcpdump.pcap host hostA and udp
```

to up the length to "a lot", write the data to a file and use `host` rather than `src` to capture the data in both directions. Essentially you are missing the word `and` between `src` and `udp`.